# Relationship between thermodynamics and steric hindrance in reaction outcomes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, kinetics

I am investigating reactions with alkyl-substituted amines ($\ce{R} = \ce{Me}, \ce{Et}, \ce{^iPr}, \ce{^tBu}$) and a second reagent, in which product Z is formed. $\Delta G$ for all of these transformations is negative.

When the amine substituent is large ($\ce{R} = \ce{^tBu}$), only product Z is formed. When the amines are small ($\ce{R} = \ce{Me}, \ce{Et}$), product Z does not form at all; rather, a mixture of many components is generated. Clearly, steric hindrance influences the outcomes.

Is it correct to infer that the activation barriers in the reactions leading to the mixture of components (i.e. when $\ce{R} = \ce{Me}, \ce{Et}$) is too high when $\ce{R} = \ce{^tBu}$, which is why that amine reacts differently and forms product Z only?

What is a general statement that can be made about the kinetics and thermodynamics of this reactivity?

Comment: To be honest, it's going to be difficult to say anything without knowing what the reaction is. As it stands, I would argue the question is unclear and cannot really be answered. I understand these things are *top secret* because you don't want me scooping you on the publication, but even just knowing the form of the reactants and products (without specifying reagents or catalysts) might help a lot more already. That said, unless you can provide a full mechanism (or a hypothesised mechanism), whatever answer you get here will still be an incomplete description.